# Phrase to refer to community of people who come together to exchange knowledge

Tags: phrases, expressions, slang, phrase-requests, collective-nouns

I need a two word phrase to refer to a community of people (academia + non-academia) who come together to share/exchange their knowledge/ideas openly on topics of their interests/ specializations.

I would appreciate the use of small and easier/common words for the phrase. Single words are also acceptable. Feel free to throw out your creative ideas and newly invented phrases.

Comment: Have you thrown out the Thesauri?

Comment: [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/)? [Experts Exchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com/)? [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/)? [Yahoo Groups](http://groups.yahoo.com/)?  [Usenet newsgroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet_newsgroup)? [Internet forum](http://www.google.com/search?q=Internet+forum)?

Answer (score 2):

I'd generally call that a "conference" or "convention", often abbreviated to "con" for non-professional gatherings such as Anime or Comic cons.

Answer (score 2):

Some possibilities include *skills circle, boffins' venue, experts' salon, idea tribe*.

You could make a list of a dozen "contents", that is, words suggestive of who will participate or what the subject matter will be (e.g.: *boffin, brain, expert, idea, ivory, knowledge, learner, notion, savant, scholar, skill, student, think, thought, tyro*)  and a similar list of [collectives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_collective_nouns_by_collective_term_A-K) (e.g.: *academy, bunch, circle, class, collective, colloquium, conference, forum, group, meeting, salon, seminar, society, tank, team, tribe, trust, venue*) and look at all combinations of same.

Comment: I like boffin! Put it with moot for *Boffin-moot* :)

Comment: Nice suggestions. I like them!

Comment: @AnWulf _Boffin-moot!?_ Wonderful idea for a t-shirt: "Follow Me to the Boffinmoot."

Answer (score 0):

In North Carolina, they have the annual Folkmoot (folk+[moot](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/moot#Noun)) which is a festival.

So if yu want to be creativ ... then put the "meeting subject" + moot.

Comment: Finland has the [*talkoot*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talkoot): "a gathering of
friends and neighbors to accomplish a
task, similar to a bee or a barn raising in English."